# How to ignore out of bounds values in an index array when using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I need to assign one array to another using an index array. But some values are out of bounds...

```
a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
b = np.array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14])
indexes = np.array([0, 2, 3, 5, 6])
```

`a` and `b` are the same size. If I use `a[indexes] = b`, it would throw an IndexError. I want it to ignore the out of bounds values, 5 and 6, so that `a` would become `[10, 1, 11, 12, 4]`.

I tried to do `indexes[indexes > b.size()] = 0`
but this would mess up the value at index 0.
How can this be solved?

Edit

The indexes may not necessarily be in order. For example:

```
indexes = np.array([2, 3, 0, 5, 6])
```

`a` should become `np.array([12,  1, 10, 11,  4])`

Comment: In your edit, please where does the 11 (b at index 1) come from in expected result of a?

Comment: b should match with indexes, so b[1] should go to a[index[1]]

Answer (score 4):

You can filter out those invalid indexes:

```
indexes = indexes[indexes < len(a)]

a[indexes] = b[indexes]
```

Output:

```
array([10,  1, 12, 13,  4])
```